# django filter リストでの判定ができない。

Tags: python3, django

Djangoでモデルを指定したリストのIDを持つものを抽出したいのですができません。
参考記事をもとにしてみましたがエラーが発生しました。

### バージョン

Django:4.0

### 参考記事

[Django 'objects.filter()' with list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956391/django-objects-filter-with-list)

この参考記事に書かれていることを試しました。
（1）__in

```
モデル.objects.filter(id__in=リスト)
```

id__in自体がSyntaxErrorとなります。

(2)Q()

```
qfilter = Q()
for q in リスト:
  qfilter = qfilter | Q(id=qfilter )

モデル.objects.filter(qfilter)
```

django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "OR": syntax error が表示されます。

Comment: fileter->filterでもダメでしたでしょうか。

Comment: すみません。転記ミスでした。filterメソッドです。

Comment: > id__in自体がSyntaxErrorとなります。 はコードの正確な引用とTracebackすべての引用が必要でしょう。この"日本語で適宜補った書き方"で問題があるようには見えません。"日本語で適宜補った書き方"から"本当のコード"にした時に何か失敗したと思えてしまいます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2. の方

```py
qfilter = Q()
for q in リスト:
    qfilter = qfilter | Q(id=q)

モデル.objects.filter(qfilter)
```

が正しいですね。

（ただし`__in`の方を使うべきであって、こちらを使う理由はないです）

Comment: 本当に些細なミスでした。コードもそのままでしたので、機能しないわけですね。